# How to create a backend for displaying large datasets in a web frontend

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a lot of timeseries relatet data chunked into one hour intervals in parquet files stored in aws s3 (for every hour one file). The purpose would be to have an web application displaying that data. Since we cannot crawl every parquet on s3 on request my approach would be to use ETL processes to aggregate those series and store them as single parquet and in a dynamodb table for different aggregated view like year, month, week, day, hour, or even minutes. Furthermore that processed parquet would be made available with aws athena to be queried (not from the frontend since i expect to long waiting times for the queries to be executed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a reasonable plan. I assume you want some pointers to how to achieve that?

Depending on the size of your current data set, and your requirements for querying it with Athena you may not need to do the ETL.

You can set up a table with a location that is a prefix of all the Parquet files (e.g. `s3://example/dir/` if the files are stored with keys like `s3://example/dir/2020/03/13/12/file.parquet`). If your total data set is not more than a couple of gigabytes I would recommend this. If your data set is larger, and it is organised into prefixes that contain each day or hour, you can create a partitioned table and add partitions with locations that use the prefix structure (e.g. `s3://example/dir/2020/03/13`, `s3://example/dir/2020/03/12` for daily partitions or `s3://example/dir/2020/03/13/11` and s3://example/dir/2020/03/13/12` for hourly partitions). Unless you have hundreds of gigabytes of data per day, or the queries you will run with Athena almost always only look at a few hours of data, I would recommend partitioning by date rather than hour to keep the number of partitions down.

If your existing Parquet files are very small, less than a hundred megabytes, and performance for the Athena queries is very important, you could try to ETL the files into bigger files to see if it helps. It may or may not, it will depend. I recommend that you use Athena itself for the ETL. You can use [`INSERT INTO`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-insert-into-etl.html) to create new partitions in a table based on data in another table. I suggest automating this by creating an [Event Bridge rule with a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/run-lambda-schedule.html) that either triggers a Lambda function that runs the conversion query in Athena, or a Step Functions state machine if you want to avoid paying for the Lambda sitting idle waiting for the query to finish (or need to wait more than 15 minutes). AWS has a service called Glue ETL which was made for this kind of thing, but in my experience it is not worth it. Using Athena, Lambda, and Step Functions beats it in terms of usability and flexibility.

You can use the same mechanism for loading pre-calculated time series into DynamoDB – use Event Bridge to schedule a Lambda function that runs queries in Athena, and convert the results to store in DynamoDB. Use Step Functions to avoid paying for idle time when waiting for the queries to finish.

If Amazon Timestream ever gets released it may be a better target for storing the time series than DynamoDB. Also consider storing the pre-calculated time series as JSON, CSV, or Apache Arrow on S3 instead of DynamoDB, that can be cheaper and in some ways simpler depending on your use case.

Please let me know if you want more details on how to set up the partitioned Athena tables, but provide some more context so I can make it more concrete.

Comment: thanks for you input. We have already an s3 structure like you mentioned in place. I was more worried about the ETL and i will investigate that further with your ideas. Unfortunately the Timestream is not there but s3 sounds better that the dynamo since we might hit limits when insertig pre-calculated values

Comment: we ended up in loading all the data into dynamodb as not further querying was required. Therefore we aggregated the values by minute, hour and day and added that as hashkey  as suffix `_day` and so on. The sortkey was the timestamp and that behaves really fast in terms of a frontend as you can query the desired level of aggregation. Since timestream is released we too we could switch but I don't see any benefits since dynamodb is super cheap

Comment: Thank you @emilio for circling back on this and tell us where you ended up.

Comment: I have a total of 68,000 records and want to display them in the front end with pagination. The first time it displayed 1000 records. I sent requests in the backend again with the next token in the recursive function. It will collect data and add it to the front end. But the problem is after 2 or 3 requests, I get a null next token.

Comment: @emilio I am in a similar situation. Do you mind sharing with us how much data are you dealing with? e.g. how many entries in a time series?

I was thinking of serving the data directly from the parquet file. Did you try this option? and if yes, did you find any performance issues?

My data is half hourly, labeled with `date, trading_period`. The UI needs to retrieve the values for a particular period of time and possibly ask for `daily` and `monthly` aggregates.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: If you use iceberg or delta tables it might give you a decent performance, based on the partitions you choose. With AWS Athena you can provision such tables and further provide jobs to build aggregates (you might use spark for it as it can be hard with sql). But we did not use it for serving a web layer as there can be potentially a lot of queries. We still use dynamodb as it is cheaper for our current use case as a layer in between holding a selection of frequently queried data